# Cómo lograr que la etiqueta de un componente en Angular, no afecte al DOM

Tags: html, angular, dom, tablas

Resumiendo de manera sencilla, tengo una tabla en HTML.
Es muy extenso el `<thead></thead>` y también es muy extenso el `<tbody></tbody>`.
Quiero colocar en un nuevo componente, el contenido de cada fila.
Este es mi código y posteriormente detallaré el problema:

```
 <table class="table table-responsive">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="col-s col-1"></th>
                ....
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <ng-container *ngFor="let order of getOrdersPipe(arrayOfHistorical); trackBy: trackById; index as i">
                <app-row [order]="order" [viewSelected]="viewSelected"></app-row>
            </ng-container>
         </tbody>
</table>
```

y dentro de `<app-row>`

```
<tr>
    <td>
    ....
    </td>
    <td>
    ....
    </td>
</tr>
```

El problema que me genera esto es que  interfiere en el DOM y la tabla me lo detecta como si todo perteneciera a la primer columna.

Estuve probando distintas formas para intentar que en el DOM no interfiera  y no encontré forma.

Por otra parte también traté de enviar la etiqueta `<tbody>` y el `*ngFor` dentro del componente pero sigue ocurriendo lo mismo. Todo el contenido se coloca en la primer columna.

El objetivo final del código es que quede más o menos de la siguiente forma:

Sin saber si hay que agregar `thead`, `tbody` y si el ciclo for se recorrería dentro de rows o solo se enviaría un elemento a un row como sucede ahora.

Se que la etiqueta `<ng-container>` no afecta al DOM, pero no termina sirviendo para lo que quiero hacer (que `<app-row>` no afecte al DOM).

Por otra parte, creo que una posible solución es que trate todos los elementos de la tabla con  y exigirles un ancho determinado. Pero no me parece lo más conveniente porque no estaría representando con las etiquetas los verdaderos elementos del HTML.

Comment: alguna razón en particular de usar un componente `app-row` en vez de `<tr *ngFor="...">`

Comment: Por un tema de re-renderizacion y estructuración del código.
Cuando ocurren eventos o cambia un @Input(), se re renderiza mi arreglo y la idea es tenerlo en otro componente a parte para que eso no pase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes intentar lo siguiente
En tu component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'tr[app-row]',
  ...
})
```

tu html ya no tendría el `tr` solo tendría los `td`

```
<td>
    {{...}}
</td>
<td>
    {{...}}
</td>
```

y luego en el html (del padre digamos)

```
<tr app-row *ngFor="..." [order]="order" [viewSelected]="viewSelected">
```

si... te olvidas del `ng-container`

Comment: Muchas gracias. Era lo que necesitaba. No conocía esa forma de llamar a los selectores. Tiene algún nombre?

Comment: la forma normal que conocemos se llama "Selector as element name", esta que te mostré se llama "Selector as attribute" y también existe "Selector as class"